# AC mains on DC ground

Tags: power-supply, ac

I have a very simple question. I have an array of AC to DC converters from well known companies such as Meanwell, Delta Electronics, Recom Power, XP Power etc. They take my 230V 50Hz AC mains and convert it to a DC output (24V, 100W in my case). However, when I use an AC voltage tester on the DC lines, I detect the presence of AC voltage. In my case I get an AC voltage of 90-100V (RMS) on the voltmeter when I measure the AC voltage of the DC ground/ 24V with respect to the neutral. Is this because of poor AC mains or is the AC-DC converter not good enough in the sense that it does not filter AC mains well enough from the DC lines? Or am I missing something quite obvious?
[image]

Comment: Edited main post with pic. It's very crude but I hope you get where I am reading AC voltage on the DC lines.

Comment: Highly related, if not a duplicate: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/127104/smps-gives-electric-shock

Comment: Search for Y capacitor leakage and you will get plenty of information on this subject.

Comment: Do these power supplies have mains earth connection and did you leave it unconnected? If yes, it explains the voltage and you must connect earth to equipment that needs it. I've read enough different Meanwell datasheets to know they also explicitly say the earth must be connected

Comment: How do you know the DC voltage is referenced to the AC neutral at all? If it's an isolated power supply you will see this issue unless to activly ensure both AC and DC sides are references to the same neutral.

Comment: Q!: Is the output DV negative connected to chassis ground? Q2: Does the supply have a 3 wire power connector but no earth wire?

Comment: What do you mean by "AC to DC converter"? Is it a battery charger (with no filtering inside) or a DC power supply or something else???

Comment: Could you give us the exact make and model of the device you made this measurement with?

Comment: @Justme, I am using AC/DC converters such as RPS-120-24 by Meanwell, CUS100ME24 by TDK-Lambda and MDS-100APS24 BA by Delta Electronics. I am trying to find the place on these converters where I can connect the earth lead. I cannot find one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not provided enough information for a certain answer - eg is output DC -ve connected to input / chassis ground?, are you using a 3 wire mains lead with ground or a 2 wire lead?, is the psu designed to use a 3 wire mains lead with ground?, ...

However ....

In many cases this sort of problem is caused by operating a power supply designed to have a 3 wire power lead with a ground connection with 2 wire mains input with no ground connection, plus output negative is connected to chassis ground and to the (missing) ground wire.

The remaining part of the puzle is the provision of two "Y capacitors" between each mains lead and chassis ground as part of an input noise filter. When a ground lead is connected the chassis ground is at ground potential and all is well.
If the ground wire is missing the capacitor midpoint is at about 1/2 mains potential and so the chassi ground AND the output negative are also.

If you use a typical DMM set to AC volts the meter impedance (typically 1- M Ohm ish) and the capacitor impedances form a voltage divider and so the measured voltage is somewhat less that 1/2 mains.

**Solutions:**

Correct: Add a ground lead in the input cord and / or power socket.

Naughty: Remove the 2 x Y capacitors - typically 0.001 uF or 0.01 uF or thereabouts.

---

Did it work?

Comment: Thanks Jim and Russell for the help. The DC ground (-ve) is not connected to the chassis ground. Also, where do I add my earth lead in my circuit above? From what I see, many AC/DC converters do not come with an earth lead. For example, check this AC/DC design by TI: https://www.ti.com/lit/df/tidrus6/tidrus6.pdf - Does this design have a earth lead because I can see SGND and PGND Nets only. Or am I missing something. I just realised that mains Neutral is not earth referenced: Basically neutral and earth are open circuit when measured on my multimeter.

Comment: @DarienRodrigues In that diagram see C10 & C15 at top left. They are the Y caps I referred to. They connect to a "SGND" symbol - as does the output VDC. Note that pin 2 on the mains connector is unnamed but connects to SGND. Without a grounded wire on that pin that cct would do EXACTLY what I described and would measure much as you measure for the reason I said.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I see C11 and C17 are also Y capacitors. Is it then recommended that SGND (DC ground as well in this case) in that circuit be connected to earth reference? Does that not affect Power supply noise? Also, if neutral is earth referenced, DC ground also gets connected to mains neutral. Is that a good thing? Doesn't that create ground loops?

Comment: Y cap midpoint is always meant to be mains ground which should be chassis ground and is often also DCout -ve connected. ||  It is designed to have the input Y caps mains grounded - this assists noise filtering. AND if not mains ground connected then the SGND WILL float at about VACmains/2.  | Neutral and earth are connected at the main switchboard only. This is part of the protective grounding system. There is no earth loop as long as Neutral is NOT connected to ground anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks alot Russell. That explains alot. I will connect my SGND to earth. But if the power supply I get doesn't have it's neutral connected to earth (I am assuming the electricity supply people need to do that when the mains enters the building) , then I will still have SGND floating at VAC/2 right?

Comment: At least the Meanwell is a medical grade supply - it has better leakage specs than normal supplies. It does not even have earth ground terminal. So it most likely won't have Y caps in the filter. It may just be so well isolated. One way is of course to earth the DC output, but I do not know what the regulations say how to ground medical devices.

Comment: @Darlen What country are you in? | NOBODY connects neutral to ground in the equipment. As above, neutral and ground are connected together ONLY at the main switchboard. With this switchboard connection made then connecting SGND to the ground lead will short out the voltage from the Y caps. The drop due to the Y current through the ground lead will be minimal.

Comment: My understanding is that Earth is usede exclusively for safety in surge preotection and as elementary safety for humans in electric devices. It's (or should be) always sonnected to the chassi and any other metallic parts of the appliance if any.

Comment: @Fredled Correct - PLUS it's an essential part of fuse blowing and earth leak tripping protection. (Fuse blowing is both anti-shock and anti fire). || You'll be pleased to know that none of that contradicts anything I said. The connection should be returned to the power socket earth / ground socket via the earth / ground lead in a 3 wire power cord and from there via the house fixed wiring ground lead to the switchboard. It is usually connected to Neutral at and only at the switchboard. it MUST NOT be joined to neutral at any other point inside the home.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, I'm in India. Most of our mains supplies have AC Neutral referenced to earth by the electricity supplier. But the building where I have put up temporarily, doesn't have this arrangement, which makes it very risky from a safety standpoint. I will attend to that. I connected by DC GND in the my AC/DC converter to earth, and it works just fine with no AC detected on my DC output. I will not connect earth to neutral though. I guess I will risk tripping several other houses' MCBs.

Comment: @Justme, The meanwell AC/DC I used had the DC Ground output connected to the earthing point provided (which I didn't notice earlier). Connecting the earthing point to earth gets rid of the my DC output floating on top of VACmains/2. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DarienRodrigues Goa? (by name). || The fact that ground connection works means that neutral and ground are joined SOMEWHERE by the supplier - as you'd hope. Probably at the local supply transformer if not at the building switchboard. ||I'd be wary of Indian buildings where corners have been cut in some areas (although that MAY meet Indian code with earthing at transformer). I'm sure you have seen buildings where builders cut corners too much and they failed during construction. They seem to be left standing - perhaps as a warning to others :-(.  My wife and I saw several such in Maharashtra.

Comment: Yes my home is in Goa. And the grounding there is perfect. I'm in Bangalore. Both my office power supply and my home supply in Goa have less than an ohm resistance between earth and neutral when measured with a meter. But the place I have rented in Bangalore did not have this. But I guess it has been connected somewhere. I am also considering adding a RCCB/GFCI in series with my voltage stabilizer to make my home lab safer. Yes, a few electricians do not bother to connect the neutral to earth. Infact, my home earthing was done properly with earthing salt and charcoal, and we water it everyday.

Comment: @DarienRodrigues  RCCB is a very very very good idea indeed - much harder to kill yourself with one installed.  If you are on facebook - [this](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1542554345818055&set=a.1574093795997443&type=3&theater) is what can happen without an RCCB in circuit. (That's me :-) ). (If no facebook [this](https://scontent.fakl2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/19787183_1542554345818055_2599547560017149665_o.jpg?_nc_cat=104&_nc_sid=0be424&_nc_ohc=CekMe0rXVq4AX9PzU6D&_nc_ht=scontent.fakl2-1.fna&oh=97f6b5837df2568a6d9561b82aca43c0&oe=5E966F66) = image only Ctrl-scroll to resize.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming the power supply is designed to provide galvanic isolation between the AC input and DC output, ask yourself this: "When measuring the potential difference (the voltage) between two nodes that are galvanically isolated, what voltage should one expect to measure?"  The answer is, "It could be just about anything."

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fft4mom.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1.   What voltage does VM1 measure between Earth ground (neutral) on the primary side and either transformer wire on the secondary side, when the transformer's primary and secondary are galvanically isolated from each other?*

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY5vIem.png)</sup>

*Figure 2.   What voltage does VM1 measure between Earth ground (neutral) on the primary side and signal ground on the secondary side? (NB: Earth ground and signal ground are galvanically isolated; they are not at the same potential.)*

---

Imagine measuring the potential difference (voltage) between the AC neutral line and the negative "-" terminal on a battery, where the AC power source and battery are galvanically isolated. What voltage would one measure in this case? Very likely it'll be an AC voltage: but what does that measurement mean when the meter is connected to two nodes that are galvanically isolated?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTe62Rm.png)</sup>

*Figure 3.*

---

And for what it's worth, isolation transformers have parasitic capacitance between the primary and secondary windings, and between the windings and the transformer's metal enclosure/chassis. This capacitance can and does contribute to the potential difference (the voltage) between Earth ground on the primary and signal ground on the secondary. See Andy aka's answer to this post on EE.SE, [Isolation transformer and AC potential between grounds](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/207894/79842).

Comment: If the output DC -ve is NOT connected to input chassis ground this answer is more likely correct and mine wrong. || If the output DC -ve IS connected to input chassis ground then my answer is probably the correct one. The OP needs to advise whether there is a DC connection from output -ve to chassis ground.

Comment: The DC -ve is not connected to chassis ground (earth). Am I also correct in understanding that many newer AC/DC modules that use Power Factor Correction circuits and switching converters do not necessarily use an isolation XFMR or for that matter even a step down XFMR? I see alot of Common mode chokes and inductors, but not XFMRs. In this design for example: https://www.ti.com/lit/df/tidrus6/tidrus6.pdf , Is the SGND the earth/chassis Ground here? It doesn't seem like. Where do I add earth in my circuit here? I also need to try and get my neutral line earth referenced. My earth is floating

Comment: My first thought was using a rectifier, hopefully your answer helps the OP

Comment: @DarienRodrigues, in the TI PDF you reference, on sheets 1 and 3, transformer T1 (sheet 1, coordinates B4) and transformer T2 (sheet 3, coordinates A3) provide galvanic isolation from mains power. Optocouplers U7 (sheet 1, C4) and U13 (sheet 3, C4) also provide mains isolation for the BULK signal line which is not isolated from mains power.  SGND is connected to EARTH ground; see sheet 1, A1, power entry jack J2.

Comment: "I also need to try and get my neutral line earth referenced. My earth is floating". I recommend you contact an electrician who is certified, licensed, and insured to fix this issue immediately.  A floating (ungrounded) neutral line is a dangerous situation.

Comment: Jim Fischer LOL. I guess he wouldn't have any power in his place if it was the case. He means the Earth (the green and yellow cable) line is floating. Which is also not very safe but not as bad.

Comment: Thanks alot for your input. @RussellMcMahon, I think the biggest learning for me was that DC ground is earth referenced in some AC/DC designs. I was checking my laptop chargers though. DC ground of 19.5V/6A output is not connected (not shorted) to earth pin of the AC input of the charger. Yet, I do not have DC ground floating on top of VACmains/2. I guess they have some other way of referencing DC ground to earth while providing galvanic isolation. I've realised AC/DC converters nowadays do not always have XFMRs on AC lines. Isolation is provided post bridge rectifier in the switching parts.

Comment: @JimFischer It does seem from his answer that it was the Y caps divider issue.

Answer (score 1):

simply I can answer for above mentioned issue that consider first fundamentals of electricity, there in diagram,I'm observing that the tester voltmeter is connected with nutral in mains and negative in DC, for this condition voltmeter can read only loop voltage and for open circuit it shows zero, however for all negative or another half cycle voltmeter can show the deflection with respect to negative of dc as it provides the reference to that of mains for voltmeter, also the overall dropped voltage/RMS voltage will be shown by meter due to their electrical structural configuration and the way/order of its connection. Keep in mind that voltmeter always needs reference voltage that is zero and this can read only loop voltage where as for ameter these conditions are not applicable.

Comment: A little bit hard to understand your explanation. Yet voted it up for your effort. In my own non-professinal terms, I would say it's parasitic current (therefore very very low but with a voltage being not rms but half (?) that of the 230VAC main. This current should be irrelevant for the fonctionality of the supply and won;t appear between the + and the - at DC side.

Answer (score 1):

Good observation.  In my opinion the DC side negative is referenced to a floating ground not with respect to the ac mains ground. Why should it be any way ? If one takes care of measurement  of DC side voltage through an isolator its fare enough is it not ? Only thing is in the case given by you if the voltages are measured with out isolating the ac ground and dc reference. The probes used may get damaged because 90 volts is applied across it.

Answer (score 0):

No point to measure voltage between neutral and dc ground. Dc ground is supposed to be isolated from neutral line. Your digital volt meter can give false ac voltage reading, depending on input impedance and surrounding electrical noise.